# How to read and pass two values inside an anonymous object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `Product_Order` table which contains `OrderId`, `ProductId` and `Quantity`(quantity of same product in an order). The code below were suppose to calculate every row of same products within an order, but changes were made so I only need to read from `Product_Order.Quantity` to get the value.

But I'm not sure how to pass both values from `Product.Name` and `Product_Order.Quantity` to `Name` and `Amount` in code below.

```
public ActionResult GetOrder(Guid id) {

     var currentOrder = db.Orders.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

     var returnOrder = new {

         FirstName = currentOrder.User.FirstName,       
        .....
         Products = currentOrder.Product_Order.GroupBy(x => x.Product.Name).Select(y => new { 

            Name = y.Key, 
            Amount = y.Count() 
            })
        })
     };                 

    return Json(returnOrder);
}
```

---Ajax:

```
 $.post("/Home/GetOrder", { "id": orderId },
                function (data) {
                    if (data) {

                        $.each(data.Products, function(index, item) {
                            Alert(item.Name +" "+ item.Amount); 
                        });
```

Comment: You do not need the `.GroupBy()` - its just `Products = currentOrder.Product_Order.Select(x => new { Name = x.Product.Name, Amount = x.Quantity }`

Comment: And for 3 questions out of 3 question, you have not provided any of the relevant information, and this could never have been answered without working through the other 2. Strongly recommend you read the help files before asking any further questions.

Comment: You should read [ask].

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for feedback, wasn't aware how bad my question were. I will give it a read :) However, there's some weird bug going on. Using the name attribute `Amount` will always result value `1`, if I change it to anything else like `Quantity`(yes, changed both in your code and `item.Quantity` in View), I get `undefined`. I'm using your code. I think the name `Amount`is bugged, or maybe it's the Anonymous object that mess things up?

Comment: @StephenMuecke setting  `Amount = 5 ` still results `1`..  -> `Products = readOrder.Product_Order.Select(x => new { Name = x.Product.Name, Amount = 5 })`. So I guess the name `Amount` is messing it somehow.. I'm not touching it anywhere else in my project.

Comment: Sorry, but what your claiming is simply impossible unless you have other code causing the issue which you have not shown. And if you change it to `Quantity = x.Quantity` then you also need to change the script to use `item.Quantity`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I changed in script as well. Both in your code and in script. After restarting visual studio and chrome made it work, without touching any code. I guess it could be my browsers or something that hanged. Anyway thanks for your help :) I will try improve my question in future.